# Unset a session after X hours

Tags: php

How do i unset a session after 12hours?

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include 'conn.php';

    $q1 = "
        SELECT 
            id
        FROM 
            sessions
        WHERE
            session_id = '".$_SESSION['session_id']."' 
        AND
            user_ip = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."' 
        AND
            user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'
    ";

    if(!$r1 = $Mysqli->query($q1))
    {
        echo 'Something wrong happend!. '. $Mysqli->error;
    }
?>
```

Login.php

```
<?php
include('check.php');
include('header.php');
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{ 

    $login_user = $Mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['gebruikersnaam']); 
    $login_pass = $Mysqli->real_escape_string(sha1($_POST['wachtwoord']));
    $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    srand ((double) microtime( )*1000000);
    $session_id = rand(1000,1000000);

    $q1 = "
    SELECT 
        id,
        username,
        block
    FROM 
        users
    WHERE
        username = '".$login_user."'  
    AND
        password = '".$login_pass."'
    ";

        if(!$r1 = $Mysqli->query($q1))
    {

        echo 'Er is een fout opgetreden!. '. $Mysqli->error;

    }


            elseif($Mysqli->affected_rows == 1)
            {


                            while ($row = $r1->fetch_assoc ())
                            { 

                                    $_SESSION["username"] = $row['username']; 
                                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];   
                                    $_SESSION['user_ip'] = $user_ip;
                                    $_SESSION['session_id'] = $session_id;

                                if ($row['block'] == 1)
                                {
                                    echo 'Je bent geblokkeerd, je kunt niet meer    inloggen!';
                                } 
                                    else 
                                    { 
                                        //Inloggen gelukt!!
                                        echo 'U bent ingelogd, <a href="index.php">Klik hier</a>';
                                    }




                $q2 = "
                INSERT INTO
                    sessions
                (
                    user_id,
                    session_id,
                    user_ip
                )
                VALUES
                (
                    '".$row['id']."',
                    '".$session_id."',
                    '".$user_ip."'
                )
                ";
                            }

                                if (!$Mysqli->query ($q2) )
                                {

                                    echo 'Er is een fout opgetreden!'. $Mysqli->error;

                                }




            }
                else 
                {   
                    echo 'Gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord onjuist, probeer het opnieuw!'; 
                }  

} 
    else 
    {
        ?>
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>Login</title>
            </head>
            <body>

            <h2>Login</h2>

            <?php 
                if(isset($_GET['error']))
                {
                    if($_GET['error'] == 'sess')
                    {
                        echo 'De sessie is ongeldig! Log aub opnieuw in!<p>';
                    }
                } 
            ?>
                <form method='post'>  
                            <table>  
                                <tr>  
                                    <td>Gebruikersnaam:</td>  
                                    <td><input type='text' name='gebruikersnaam'></td>  
                                </tr>  
                                <tr>  
                                    <td>Wachtwoord:</td>  
                                    <td><input type='password' name='wachtwoord'></td>  
                                </tr>  
                                <tr>  
                                    <td><input type='submit' name='submit'     value='Login'></td>  
                                </tr>  
                            </table>  
                </form>

            </body>
            </html>           
    <?php
    }   
    include('footer.php');
    ?>
```

In the reactions is
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',60*12);

where do i place it? and option 2 where can i place that?

Could you please help me? if you need more information, ask it.

Answer (score 0):

Set time to delete session after 12 hours.

**Method 1:**

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',60*12);// 60 minutes * 12
```

**Method 2:**

```
 <?php
 $inactive = 3600 * 12;// 12 hours

 $session_life_sid = time() - $_session['timeout'];

 if($session_life_sid > $inactive)
 {
 session_destroy();
 session_unset();
 }

$_session['timeout']=time();//Set this timeout session when you are setting session for session_id and user_id
```

Comment: Where do i need to place it?

Comment: place the method 1 where you set session for session_id and user_id

Comment: yeah.place where you set $_SESSION['user_id']=somevalue and the other

Comment: I added login.php, could you say where? Some errors are dutch (because im dutch)

Comment: After these lines                                            $_SESSION["username"] = $row['username']; 
 $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];   
 $_SESSION['user_ip'] = $user_ip;
 $_SESSION['session_id'] = $session_id;
 ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',60*12);

Comment: Alright, now lets wait 12 hours :P

Comment: test it now by setting its value to 1-2 min.If its working now then also works for 12 hours too :P

Comment: How? 1*1? to test it?

Comment: ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',1);// 1 minute.replace with 2 etc whatever you want

Comment: it isn't working? Im still online

http://prntscr.com/3iapr2

Comment: add this on first line session_start(); of login.php after php starting tag

Comment: it is not the exact time as depends on `session.gc_probability` and `session.gc_divisor`. http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime

Comment: Now i have this: ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',60); still not working